# Password protected directory doesn't prompt

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm running a windows NT server for which I only have FTP access. I am trying to password protect a directory using .htaccess / .htpasswd but regardless of having it installed I am still able to access the pages in the directory without a prompt.

My .htaccess looks like this.

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
# path has been blocked out
AuthUserFile \hshome\xxx\xxx\xxx/.htpasswd
Options +FollowSymLinks
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from All
Require valid-user
Allow from env=allow
```

What would cause this to happen?

Comment: You tagged your question with both `apache` and `iis`... Which one are you using? If it's the latter, no amount of `.htaccess` will make it work.

Comment: `AuthUserFile \hshome\xxx\xxx\xxx/.htpasswd` – and that is supposed to be an actual absolute path on a Win NT system …?